# Seconds to Days, Hours and Minutes (customizable day length)

Tags: c++

I have a loop and in every loop I get the current seconds the application has been running for I then want to convert this time into how many, Days, Hours and Seconds that the seconds calculate to but not 'real time' I need to be able to customize how many seconds are in a day, I have tried examples on SO and the web but nothing seems to be out there for this. I have some defines

```
#define DAY             1200
#define HOUR            DAY / 24
#define MINUTE          HOUR / 60
#define SECOND          MINUTE / 60
```

So in my define a day would last for 1200 seconds. I have then been trying to convert elapsed seconds into 'my' seconds

```
seconds_passed = fmodf(SECOND, (float)(GetTicks() / 1000));
```

Which returns what SECOND equals (0.013889) but then every loop is the same, it never changes I was thinking I would just be able to convert for example: 1real second into 1.25fake seconds then

```
Minute = (seconds_passed / MINUTE);
seconds_passed = fmodf(seconds_passed, MINUTE);
```

work out how many (fake)minutes, (fake)hours and (fake)days have elapsed since the application started.

Hope that makes sense, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to customise how many seconds are in a day, all you're really doing is changing the ratio of 1 second : 1 second.

For instance, if you did was 1200 seconds in a day your ratio is:
`1:72`
that is, for every 1 second that passes in your day, it is the equivilent of 72 real seconds.

So yes basically all you need to do in your program is find the ratio of 1 second to 1 second, times your elapsed seconds by that to get the 'fake' seconds, and then use that value...
The code may look something like this:

```
// get the ratio second:fake_second
#define REAL_DAY_SECONDS 86400
int ratio = REAL_DAY_SECONDS / DAY;

fake_to_real = fake_second*ratio;
real_to_fake = real_second/ratio;
```

Comment: Do you mean 1 real second == 72 fake seconds

Comment: yes (sorry misread your comment), since a real day has 86400 seconds and your fake day has 1200, you can fit 72 fake days in a real day, which means the ratio is 1:72

Comment: oh Sorry I miss-read what you were saying, Thanks, it seems I was over complicating it

Comment: Thats ok, happens to every one :D, have fun.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own time durations with one line in chrono:

```
using fake_seconds = std::chrono::duration<float, std::ratio<72,1>>;
```

Some sample code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

using fake_seconds = std::chrono::duration<float, std::ratio<72,1>>;
 
int main()
{
    auto f_x = fake_seconds(350s);
    std::cout << "350 real seconds are:\n" << f_x.count() << " fake_seconds\n";
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/f5G86avxr